# How to my input text box and select required in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a form that I want to make everything required so when I click the Next button it goes to the next form. I'm not sure how this work but I have the "required" but it just go to the next form without showing the required error.

```
<div class="container tb-10">
<form >
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <h4>Food Stamps (SNAP) / EBT Cards:</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Please name the person (whether you or a member of your household) who receives food stamps, and city and state where they are received.</label>
                <div>
                    Person Receiving Benefits: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_beneficiary" id="snap_beneficiary" required placeholder="Person Receiving Benefits" >
                </div>

                <div>
                    Relationship to you: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_relationship" id="snap_relationship" required placeholder="Relationship to you" >
                </div>

                <div>
                    City: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_city" id="snap_city" required placeholder="City" >
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="state" class="form-label">State:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="State" id="state" required>
                        <option selected value=" ">Select State...</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" >Exit</button>
        <button id="submitform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" routerLink ="/referrals" > Next </button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-benefits',
  templateUrl: './benefits.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./benefits.component.css']
})
export class BenefitsComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your component.html file

```
<div class="container tb-10">
        <form [formGroup]="newForm">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h4>Food Stamps (SNAP) / EBT Cards:</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Please name the person (whether you or a member of your household) who receives food stamps, and city and state where they are received.</label>
                        <div>
                            Person Receiving Benefits: <input type="text" formControlName="Benefits" class="form-control" name="snap_beneficiary" id="snap_beneficiary" required placeholder="Person Receiving Benefits" >
                        </div>
                        <div
                        *ngIf="newForm.get('Benefits')?.hasError('required') "
                        class="text-danger"
                      >
                      Benefits is required.
                      </div>
        
                        <div>
                            Relationship to you: <input type="text" formControlName="Relationship" class="form-control" name="snap_relationship" id="snap_relationship" required placeholder="Relationship to you" >
                        </div>
                        <div
                        *ngIf="newForm.get('Relationship')?.hasError('required') "
                        class="text-danger"
                      >
                      Relationship is required.
                      </div>
        
        
                        <div>
                            City: <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="city" name="snap_city" id="snap_city" required placeholder="City" >
                        </div>
        
                        <div>
                            <label for="state" class="form-label">State:</label>
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="State" id="state" required>
                                <option selected value=" ">Select State...</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" >Exit</button>
                <button id="submitform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" routerLink ="/referrals" > Next </button>
            </footer>
        </form>
```

In your component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
    })
    export class FormComponent {
      newForm: FormGroup;
    
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
        this.newForm = this.fb.group({
          Benefits: ['', [Validators.required]],
          Relationship: ['', [Validators.required]],
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make it where you show the error message when I click the next button?

Comment: In the Html i have kept the error in a  div tag and to show hide the div tag using *ngIf directives

Answer (score 2):

I've used template driven approach to solve it.

First, make sure you are using Angular's form module in your component. You need to import the FormsModule in your app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    FormsModule, // or ReactiveFormsModule if you are using reactive forms
  ],
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's the modified HTML:

```
<div class="container tb-10">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitFun()">
      <div class="row">
        <h4>Food Stamps (SNAP) / EBT Cards:</h4>
        <div>
            Person Receiving Benefits: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_beneficiary"
              id="snap_beneficiary" [(ngModel)]="formData.snap_beneficiary" required placeholder="Person Receiving Benefits">
          </div>
          
          <div>
            Relationship to you: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_relationship"
              id="snap_relationship" [(ngModel)]="formData.snap_relationship" required placeholder="Relationship to you">
          </div>
          
          <div>
            City: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_city" id="snap_city" [(ngModel)]="formData.snap_city"
              required placeholder="City">
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <label for="state" class="form-label">State:</label>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="State" id="state" name="state" [(ngModel)]="formData.state" required>
              <option selected value="">Select State...</option>
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">Exit</button>
      <button id="submitform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" > Next</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

In your component TypeScript file, you should define formData to store the form values and create the onSubmit method to handle form submission and validation:

Import and declare router in ts component file

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


  formData: any = {}; 

  constructor(private router: Router ) {

 

  onSubmitFun() {
    // Check if the form is valid
    if (this.validateForm()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/referrals']);
    }
  }

  validateForm(): boolean {
    // Perform custom validation if needed
    if (!this.formData.snap_beneficiary || !this.formData.snap_relationship || !this.formData.snap_city || !this.formData.state) {
      // Display validation error message or perform other actions
      return false; // Form is not valid
    }
    return true; // Form is valid
  }
```

Comment: You don't show the error message.

Comment: This don't have the error messages